# Moving magento site to live server results an error

Tags: magento-1.9, hosting, localhost

I am trying to move my magento site from local to live server, but I get this error.

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 636829790955

I tried changing local.xml.sample to local.xml to see the problem also. I changed dbname, host, username and password inside app/etc/local.xml also. How to correctly upload the magento site? What are the steps to do so?

Comment: hi.. for  checking the issue rename local.xml from local.xml.sample at yourmagentodir/errors

Comment: Try following through the steps at http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/158 to find the complete error.

Comment: go to /var/report/636829790955 and tell us what is the real error.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything else, it would be wise to empty all of the cached content.

Log into the manager, then: Site --> Clear Cache
Clear your sessions: Security --> Flush All Sessions

Comment: Actually, before clearing cache, make sure file/directory permissions are set properly so Magento can write to the `var/` directory. Most problems arise because Magento can't write sessions files, report files and sometimes will partially recover and write cache files to the system `/tmp` folder. This is the root cause of the amazingly non-clearable cache everyone runs into where you change the base urls in the database, can see they've changed but no amount of clearing cache allows them to be read.

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow below Steps.

**1.** Open your **core_config_data** table in phpMyAdmin.

**2.** Find the following rows for your **unsecure section**, they should look like the following:

```
PATH                         VALUE
web/unsecure/base_url        http://www.mydomain.com/
web/unsecure/base_link_url   {{unsecure_base_url}}
web/unsecure/base_skin_url   {{unsecure_base_url}}skin/
web/unsecure/base_media_url  {{unsecure_base_url}}media/
web/unsecure/base_js_url     {{unsecure_base_url}}js/
```

**3.** Replace **http://www.mydomain.com/** with your appropriate domain url (trailing slash necessary) and if you’ve installed in a subfolder append it with a / after it.

**4.** Find the following rows for your **secure section**, they should look like the following:

```
PATH                         VALUE
web/secure/base_url          https://www.mydomain.com/</td></tr>
web/secure/base_link_url     {{secure_base_url}}</td></tr>
web/secure/base_skin_url     {{secure_base_url}}skin/</td></tr>
web/secure/base_media_url    {{secure_base_url}}media/</td></tr>
web/secure/base_js_url       {{secure_base_url}}js/</td></tr>
```

**5.** Replace **https://www.mydomain.com/** with your appropriate domain url (trailing slash necessary) and if you've installed in a subfolder append it with a / after it. If you haven't received your security certificate and enabled TLS/SSL yet, use **http** instead of **https**

**6.** Clear **/var/cache**, **/var/session** after changing base_urls and when you have access to your system reindex your **URL_rewrite index**. Clearing cache and sessions is necessary because your config is cached and clearing it forces a reread of the configuration data from the core_config_data table and reestablishment of sessions with the proper information.

**NOTE:** IF YOU HAVE SET YOUR BASE_URL correctly for **web/unsecure/base_url** and **web/secure/base_url** YOU DO NOT HAVE TO MESS AROUND WITH CHANGING THE **{{UNSECURE_BASE_URL}}** and **{{SECURE_BASE_URL}}** MACROS in the rest of the entries.

This is going to definitely work.

Comment: I did it but I get this error.Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720 bytes)

Comment: Heh, 32M memory limit. On shared hosting. Usual memory_limit issue, increase it to 256M, if it won't increase, find a capable Magento host.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check in `var/report/` for a file named with that number. Read its contents for stack trace that outlines the issue causing Magento to die
2. If no files are present in `var/report/` then file/directory permissions haven't been properly set. Set file/directory permissions recursively for var/ so that the web server can write temporary files

Generally, file permissions are set as follows:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod o+w var app/etc
chmod 550 mage
chmod -R o+w media
```

[Steps needed to move Magento to a different web server.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35087/how-can-we-stop-a-magento-site-clone-from-redirecting-back-to-live-site/35119#35119)