# Change BaseUrl without backend access

Tags: base-url

I changed the baseurl `system->configuration->web` from `mysite.com` to `mysite.com/mysite` trying to fix an error.  Problem is now i can't get into the backend to change it back.  Does someone know a fix for this without backend access?

Comment: Magento question as old as time, you edit or send an update query to the database - for 1.x, added information that might be applicable - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35087/how-can-we-stop-a-magento-site-clone-from-redirecting-back-to-live-site/35119#35119

Comment: you are completely right.  I had gone through all the forums and did the trial and error approach but it was just not working out.  Magento has so many variables.  But anyway I was able to get it working...Finally!  For anyone else that might have a similar issue, clear cache, look at the answer from Aman Alam.  That's what worked for me.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly able to update it from database by below mentioned query replace `http://domainname/` with you base url.

```
update core_config_data set value = 'http://domainname/' where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
update core_config_data set value = 'http://domainname/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Hope it will help.