# Magento Noob: Need to find the main config files for Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8

I am new to Magento.  I'm basically doing archaeology on an old site that was abandoned by a former engineer.  I'm having the following problems:

1. I can't find the "main" configuration file for Magento.  In particular I'd like to find the database connection string so I can locate the database (both in my dev and prod environments).  Where is the main config located?
2. I don't have any dev environment that is in sync with the production code.  I would like to copy everything from the production site (everything is still running there, and I'm afraid to touch anything) and create a fresh dev environment.  What settings do I need to make sure I change to ensure the dev environment is isolated from the production environment?  (e.g. I don't want to have the dev environment accidentally pointing to the production database, or anything else it shouldn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Magento main config file locate at **app/etc/local.xml** you can see database related details in same file
2. For creating dev environment - copy all product code on dev server and copy database to dev server, edit **app/etc/local.xml** add dev server database details and open database goto **core_config_data** table and change path value for **web/unsecure/base_url** and web/secure/base_url from production url to dev url that's it

Comment: I recommend checking out this answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35087/how-can-we-stop-a-magento-site-clone-from-redirecting-back-to-live-site as it has a much more comprehensive list of things that are required.