# Production clone behaving differently

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm seeing different output from my production clone site than on production.  The most obvious difference I can see so far (and there is probably more) is that the js/css references in the main document look to have been min-ified on production:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/media/css_secure/eb0df35e22a81d2150af7faddb2a014c-v2.18.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/media/js/f081fea0e1f96e90201edfc964382601-v2.18.js"></script>
```

But in my production clone, they come back like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/git/magento/skin/frontend/responsive/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/git/magento/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/git/magento/skin/frontend/base/default/css/amasty/amfpc/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/git/magento/skin/frontend/responsive/default/css/AutoComplete.css" media="all" />
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/git/magento/js/prototype/prototype.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/git/magento/js/lib/ccard.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/git/magento/js/prototype/validation.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/git/magento/js/scriptaculous/builder.min.js"></script>
...
```

There are 2 problems I see:

1. I would like my clone to have the same min-ified CSS and JS as prod
2. The CSS and JS urls for the clone start with "/git/magento" which is actually the name of my Magento ROOT folder on disk, so that's not right and they all come back as 404s.

When I did the production clone, I didn't bring over any of the files in `/media` (that's the advice I got).  Is there anything I should be doing differently?  I also followed these steps: [How can we stop a Magento site clone from redirecting back to live site?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35087/how-can-we-stop-a-magento-site-clone-from-redirecting-back-to-live-site)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we stop a Magento site clone from redirecting back to live site?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35087/how-can-we-stop-a-magento-site-clone-from-redirecting-back-to-live-site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I had to create the MAGENTO_ROOT/var and MAGENTO_ROOT/media folders and give them the correct permissions. This was very helpful: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html#privs-after

NOTE: I didn't follow everything in this article. ^  It screwed up my git repo when I did follow them at first.  The main thing I got was the permissions needed to be less restricted on MAGENTO_ROOT/var and MAGENTO_ROOT/media folders.

I guess the problem was that the /media folder was not writable to the web server process, so it couldn't save the minified/cached version of the js/css.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of product mode has enable js and css merging. So you have to disable it and refresh the cache for run product clone perfectly.

Please go to database and execute this query

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'dev%'
```

change these value from 1 to 0

```
dev/js/merge_files
dev/css/merge_css_files
```

Remove var/ folder and refresh your product clone, it should work.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, @nits.  Looks like I didn't have to disable these 2 settings because my /media and /var folders were completely empty already.  I just had to give them less restricted permissions and the problem went away.  Does that sound right to you?