# No theme and wrong redirection after moving live site to local server - Magento 1.7

Tags: migration, development, local

I've taken over responsibility of a Magento installation.
Since the installation requires updates and further progress I've decided to move a copy of the live shop to a local web server for testing puroses.

1. I've setup a Centos 7 server with php56, mariadb an further more to meet the [requirements](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html).
2. Moved the files from live server to local server - set directory permission to 0777
3. cleared /tmp , /var/session and /var/cache folders
4. Made database backup - imported database to local mariadb
5. changed web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url entry from www.mysite.com to local-server-ip/magento-folder
6. Edited app/etc/local.xml

When I open the site (local-server-ip/magento/index.php) in browser the side loads but not the theme.
And when I click on any link it redirects me to local-server-ip/magento/store_name and I got an error "File not found".

I assume the second issue is due to some SEO configuration but I don't know where this could be fixed.

Someone may know of this behavior and help to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it to work.

For anyone else who mess with this issue, those threads helped me to got it to work:
[Production clone behaving differently](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159070/production-clone-behaving-differently)
[Magento URLs other than home page do not work without index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702708/magento-urls-other-than-home-page-do-not-work-without-index-php)